# How to get data from Local storage onClick in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to use the data from local storage in javascript onClick. I have my html file and javascript file below. Thanks

```
            <fieldset>
             <form>
               <!--GET USER NAME-->
            <p>
                <label for="inName" >What is your name?</label>
                <input type="text" id="inName" name="f_name"/>
            </p>
        
            <!-- GET COLOUR--> // I m not sure about how the get color as user can 
                               //choose the color from drop down color palet.
            <p>
                <label for="inColor" >What is your favourite colour? </label>
                <input type="color" id="inColor" name="f_color" />
            </p>
            
            <p> // how to get the value when user clicks the button
                // in order to call onClick function to output the 
                  user's name and 
                // display favorite color in background.  
                <input type="submit" value="Click to save" />
            <p/>
            </fieldset>
                     </form>
```

I don't know how to get data from local storage when user click to submit the form :

```
//NOW THAT WE HAVE STORED DATA ON ONE PAGE, WE CAN ACCESS IT FROM ANY PAGE ON THIS 
  WEBSITE.
window.onload = function(){     
//GET ELEMENTS USED FOR OUTPUT
    var userOut = document.getElementById("newMsgBox");
//GET VALUES FROM COOKIES/LOCAL STORAGE
    var userName = localStorage.getItem("nameIn");
    var userColor = localStorage.getItem("inColor");
//CREATE OUTPUT WITH VALUES
if (userName !== null) {
        userOut.innerHTML = " " +userName;
    }   
}//end onload
```

Comment: What do you mean "you aren't sure" ?  We need a specific error or problem in order to help you.  Please edit your question and give debugging details (what the problem is, and where it's occurring in your code)

Comment: thanks Devlin, I don't know how to get data from local storage when user click to submit the form <input type="submit" value="Click to save" />

Comment: As a side note, when registering an event listener you should instead use the `window.addEventListener('load', function() {});` syntax which adds a listener safely, meaning it doesn't interfere with code elsewhere that might want to register a listener on that same event. When you assign a function to `window.onload`, any listeners that were previously assigned are replaced and won't be called when this event is fired.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to listener event from an specific button and then access to your localStorage you could do this:

first get the element:

```
const button = document.getElementById('<clickable_element_id>');
```

then add a listener to the button;

```
button.addEventListener("click",(event)=> {
  event.preventDefault() // only if you want to prevent the action

  //here you can access to your local store items like:
  const a = localStorage.getItem("<item you saved previously>");
  ...
});
```

Comment: thanks Luis, the button does have have id field...and I can only get element  by <input type="submit" value="Click to save" />

Comment: @Kamranqureshi  you can easily add the `id` property, here one: `<input type="submit" id="saved input" value="Click to save" />`

Comment: If you don't want to add the id attribute to your input element, you could try this `document.querySelectorAll("input[type= submit]")[0]` but whit this solution you have to be carefully because querySelectorAll will give you an arrays of element of you page with `input[type= submit]`, for that reason I recommend you put id to your input

Answer (score 0):

It's really unclear what you want to do but

```
let inColor = document.getElementById('inColor');
let inName = document.getElementById('inColor');
```

Will fetch the values for you.
I think you are looking for something like this.

```
<script>
function saveData() {
  let inColor = document.getElementById('inColor');
  let inName = document.getElementById('inName');
  localStorage.setItem("inColor", inColor);
  localStorage.setItem("inName", inName);     
}
</script>
<input type="Button" value="Click to save" onclick="saveData"/>
```

Comment: thanks Griffin, can i use as is without changing to onclick="saveData" is part of assignment to work with html file as is and plus its the form. <form name="infoForm" action="#" method="get">
  <fieldset><input type="submit" value="Click to save" /></fieldset>
 </form>

Comment: Ohh.. there is key information in that sentence..
I think that after pressing submit you browser will change url to 
http://sameasbefore/same?inName=text&inColor=color
So basically on pageload you want to get window.location.split('?')[1] to get whatever is after ? sign.
Then you split by & and for each of those you split by =

Answer (score -3):

Import Jquery and use this. I hope help you. when you click on button with id idOfBtn jquery gonna eject the event and call the localStorage with key (*key*). Replace it for you key name.

```
    $("#idOfBtn").click(function() {
     alert(localStorage.getItem('_key_'));
    });
```

Comment: thanks, but i want to javascript....i m new jquery...